# Associative property of two functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's say we have an algebra $A(M, \oplus, \otimes)$ with ($\oplus$) being an associative binary operation and ($\otimes$) being a binary non-associative operation.

Is following statement true for all $x, y, z$ from $M$?

$(x \oplus y) \otimes z == x \oplus (y \otimes z)$

It's obviously not true the other way around ($(x \otimes y) \oplus z \neq x \otimes (y \oplus z)$) as shown e.g. by integers and normal $+$ and $-$ but it seems to be true this way (at least it's true for integers).

**EDIT:** Ok, now we know that it's not universally true. But it's still true in some cases so what is the minimal set of other statements that have to be true about that $A$ for the above statement in question to be true?

Comment: It is not true. E.g. $(x\times y)-z= x\times (y-z)$ is not true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not by far. Take for example $\mathbb R^3$ with $\oplus$ being vector addition and $\otimes$ being cross product (which is the first non-associative algebra that came to mind), and then let $x=(1,0,0)$, $y=(-1,0,0)$, $z=(0,1,0)$.

Then $(x\oplus y)\otimes z$ is zero, but $x\oplus(y\otimes z)$ is $(1,0,\pm 1)$ (I don't care to remember the sign conventions right now).

---

In fact this property cannot be true for any nontrivial [*algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra) (where we require $\oplus$ to be an abelian group operation and $\otimes$ to distribute over it). Namely, we would need to have
$$ (x\otimes z)\oplus(y\otimes z) = (x\oplus y)\otimes z = x\oplus (y\otimes z) $$
and by cancelling $y\otimes z$ we get $x\otimes z = x$ for all $x$ and $z$, which is (a) not very interesting, and (b) actually associative, in contradiction to you wanting a non-associative operation.

Comment: Good point, any idea what other properties have to be true for the formula in question to be true as well?

Comment: @Petrroll: See extended answer.